# Integrate does not produce expected result

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I evaluated an integral

```
Integrate[1/Sqrt[9 x^2 + 6 x - 8], x]
```

I think the final answer should include absolute values. However, Mathematica's result does not include any. Why is this?

Comment: Edit your question to include the code (not an image of the code) that you used. Without more information we cannot help much.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I just edited my question

Comment: Why do you think the answer should have absolute value symbols?

Comment: Absolute values are not complex-differentiable. Antiderivatives should (with certain exceptions) be complex-differentiable. The exceptions involve integrands that live only in deal space e.g. the `RealAbs` function, or `DiracDelta`.

Answer (score 7):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_] = 1/Sqrt[(9 x^2) + (6 x) - (8)];
```

The integrand is complex. It is real when

```
fd = FunctionDomain[f[x], x]

(* x < -(4/3) || x > 2/3 *)

Plot[Evaluate@ReIm[f[x]], {x, -3, 3},
 PlotRange -> {-5, 5},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{Re, Im}, {0.8, 0.75}]]
```

[image]

Mathematica operates in the complex domain

```
g[x_] = Integrate[f[x], x]

(* 1/3 Log[1 + 3 x + Sqrt[-8 + 6 x + 9 x^2]] *)

Plot[Evaluate@ReIm[g[x]], {x, -3, 3},
 PlotRange -> {-1/2, 5/4},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{Re, Im}, {0.8, 0.5}]]
```

[image]

Since you are dealing with an indefinite integral, the result can be offset by any arbitrary complex constant.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica evaluates the integral

```
int = Integrate[1/(9 x^2 + 6 x - 8), x]
(*1/18 Log[2 - 3 x] - 1/18 Log[4 + 3 x]*)
```

as expected:

```
Plot[{Re[int], Im[int]}, {x, -5, 5}, GridLines -> {{-4/3, 2/3}, None}]
```

[image]